# Android - Uploading images from App to IIS Server

Tags: android, asp.net-mvc-3, web-services, wcf-data-services

I've been developing an app for a while in Android, and now I need to upload an image to a server from this app. The thing is that I really don't know how to do this in the back end (this being the server side). I've read a lot about sending images through the `httpmime` libs and using `multipart`, but none much about the server side service which receives the image.

I need to use something like MVC3 or WCF because the server we have here is IIS and I haven't found much about how to do it with this model. So any tutorial or guide about how to accomplish that with this models is what I need, any help also would be really appreciated.

Comment: Wait a moment. You are talking about ASP.NET MVC 3 and WCF Data Services. At least you have used those tags in your question. Which of them should receive the image from the client (Android) application? What do you want to do then with this image on the server once it is received? What is the relation between the ASP.NET MVC 3 application and the WCF Data Service?

Comment: well i could use any of those, not both of em at the same time, also is a rest web service i forgot to mention. is not that I want to use them both, just a rest web service with any of them, because those are the ones we need here. also to add, what I want to do is to recieve the image uploaded from the Android device and save it to a folder in the server, just that

Answer (score 1):

You can post your file trough HTTP POST

```
public String sendFilePost(String urlServer, String pathToOurFile){
                   HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                   DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
                   DataInputStream inputStream = null;
                   String lineEnd = "\r\n";
                   String twoHyphens = "--";
                   String boundary =  "*****";
                   int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
                   byte[] buffer;
                   int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
                   try
                   {
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );
                   URL url = new URL(urlServer);
                   connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                   connection.setDoInput(true);
                   connection.setDoOutput(true);
                   connection.setUseCaches(false);
                   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

                   outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
                   outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                   outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
                   outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // Read file
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                   while (bytesRead > 0)
                   {
                   outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                   }

                   outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
                   InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                   String line;
                   StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer(); 
                   while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                        response.append(line);
                   }
                   String rrrr = response.toString();
                   rd.close();
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   outputStream.flush();
                   outputStream.close();
                    return rrrr;
                   }
                   catch (Exception ex)
                   {
                       return "Something went wrong!";
                   }
               }
```

Comment: if this android side? the probem is that o don't know how to do the other side